# Given a binary array nums, return the maximum number of consecutive 1's in the array

Tags: arrays, c

I do not know why my code gives me this error -> solution.c: In function ‘findMaxConsecutiveOnes’
Line 32: Char 1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] [solution.c]
}
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors.

```
int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int* nums, int numsSize){
 
    int counter = 0;
    int max = 0;
    
    for(int i =0; i < numsSize; i++){
        if(nums[i] == 1){
            counter++;
        }
       else{
            counter = 0;
        }
        if(counter > max){
            max = counter;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", max);
}
```

This works in Code blocks but not leet code. Any idea why.

Comment: your function declared to return an int but you dont have any return statements, a compiler should at least warn you about it

Comment: Hint: what kind of value are you stating that the function will return, and are you returning that value?

Answer (score 2):

Your function promises to return an `int` but never returns a value of any type. This is why you are getting this warning/error.  Presumably you meant to return `counter` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function return type is **int** not **void** so you have to return some int value that's why you are getting the error. Your code should be:

```
 int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int* nums, int numsSize){
 
    int counter = 0;
    int max = 0;
    
    for(int i =0; i < numsSize; i++){
        if(nums[i] == 1){
            counter++;
        }
       else{
            counter = 0;
        }
        if(counter > max){
            max = counter;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", max); // it's upto you to show, if you want to show 
    //change return type to void and don't add next return statement
    return max;

}
```

I think this should resolve your error